# Count unique values over two columns per group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, distinct, count-unique

I have a data frame `Segments` with a company identifier `gvkey`, year `Year`, and two columns with an indicator of the industry the company operates in `SICS1` and `SICS2`. I would like to aggregate the data as such that I receive the count of unique industry identicators per company/year combination.

My data frame looks as follows (indicative):

```
    gvkey Year SICS1 SICS2
1    1209 2017  3569  3533
2    1209 2017  2813  3569
3    1209 2017  2813  3569
4    1209 2018  2813  3569
5    1209 2018  2813  7280
6    1209 2018  1908  3569
7    1209 2018  1412  3569
8    1209 2018  3569  3200
9    1503 2017  3569  3533
10   1503 2017  2813  3569
11   1503 2018  2813  3569
12   1503 2018  3569  3533
13   1503 2018  2813  3569
```

My desired output is should be somewhat like:

```
gvkey Year n_unique
1209  2017    3
1209  2018    6
1503  2017    3
1503  2018    3
```

What I tried to so far only gave me the unique values per column:

```
Segments %&%
group_by(gvkey, Year) %&%
summarize(across(SICS1:SICS2, n_distinct))

gvkey Year SICS1 SICS2
1209  2017   2     2
1209  2018   4     3
1503  2017   2     2
1503  2018   2     2
```

Simply summing up the unique values from `SICS1` and `SICS2` will not do the trick unfortunately, because it would result in counting some industry identifiers multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `summarise()`, you could use `across()` to select multiple columns, unlist them to vectors and count the numbers of unique values by groups.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(gvkey, Year) %>%
  summarise(n_unique = n_distinct(unlist(across(SICS1:SICS2)))) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#   gvkey  Year n_unique
#   <int> <int>    <int>
# 1  1209  2017        3
# 2  1209  2018        6
# 3  1503  2017        3
# 4  1503  2018        3
```

---

Another way is that you need to stack `SICS1` and `SICS2` together first, and then you could count the number of unique values.

```r
df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(SICS1:SICS2) %>%
  group_by(gvkey, Year) %>%
  summarise(n_unique = n_distinct(value)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! I was making it way too complicated. Your answers made me think differently about it, although it was not exactly what I was looking for. My apologies if I was not clear enough.
The following answered my problem:

```
Segments.1 <- Segments[c("gvkey", "Year", "SICS1")]
Segments.1 <- Segments.1 %>% rename(
  SICS = SICS1
)
Segments.2 <- Segments[c("gvkey", "Year", "SICS2")]
Segments.2 <- Segments.2 %>% rename(
  SICS  = SICS2
)
Segments.n <- rbind(Segments.1, Segments.2)
Diversification <- Segments.n %>% 
  group_by(gvkey, Year) %>% 
  summarize(Diversification = n_distinct(SICS))
```

Comment: You can do `Segments %>% group_by(gvkey, Year) %>% summarise(Diversification  = n_distinct(unlist(cur_data())))`